# Random selection of range from time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

So I have time series of length 324. I want to randomly select 60 
    continous time steps for each iteration
    eg. for i = 1 select 3:74 ,for I= 2 select 255:314 and so on for thousand
    times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Pick a random number `r` between 0 and 324-60.
2. Select time steps `r` to `r+60`

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np

sampleSize = 60
timeSeries = np.random.random((324, 5, 5)) # exchange this with your real data

r = np.random.randint(0, timeSeries.shape[0]-sampleSize+1)
sample = timeSeries[r:r+60]
```